# Add multiple images in one with .Net Chart Controls

Tags: .net, image, powershell, graph, charts

Written in power shell, I'm using .Net Chart Controls to create some charts, graphs. At the moment, I'm able to save those charts, graphs separately to each image file as the following:

```
$mailHash = @{"Email Set"=$emailPer;"No Email"=$noEmailPer}

$outFilePic= "C:\My Documents\Documents"

Function drawPie ($hash){

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization
    $Chart = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
    $ChartArea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
    $Series = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
    $ChartTypes = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType]

    $Series.ChartType = $ChartTypes::Pie
    $Chart.Series.Add($Series)
    $Chart.ChartAreas.Add($ChartArea)
    $Chart.Series['Series1'].Points.DataBindXY($hash.keys, $hash.values)
    $Chart.Series[‘Series1’][‘PieLabelStyle’] = ‘Disabled’

    $Legend = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend
    $Legend.IsEquallySpacedItems = $True
    $Legend.BorderColor = 'Black'
    $Chart.Legends.Add($Legend)
    $chart.Series["Series1"].LegendText = "#VALX (#VALY%)"

    $Chart.Width = 700
    $Chart.Height = 400
    $Chart.Left = 10
    $Chart.Top = 10
    $Chart.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
    $Chart.BorderColor = 'Black'
    $Chart.BorderDashStyle = 'Solid'

    $ChartTitle = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title
    $ChartTitle.Text = 'Email '
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font @('Microsoft Sans Serif','12', [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $ChartTitle.Font =$Font
    $Chart.Titles.Add($ChartTitle)
    $Chart.SaveImage($outFilePic, 'jpeg')   
}
```

Above is dynamic function to create to pie chart. Hence, many different charts will be created as well. How to save those in one image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below version, I have added multiple series and legends to the same chart object (I have made series name fetching dynamic for this) and saved it:

```
Function drawPie ($chart,$hash,$ChartT){


    $ChartArea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
    $Series = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series


    $Series.ChartType = $ChartT
    $Chart.Series.Add($Series)
    $Chart.ChartAreas.Add($ChartArea)  

    $Chart.Series[$series.name].Points.DataBindXY($hash.keys, $hash.values)
    $Chart.Series[$series.name][‘PieLabelStyle’] = ‘Disabled’
    $Chart.Series[$series.name].ChartArea = $ChartArea.name

    $Legend = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend
    $Legend.IsEquallySpacedItems = $True
    $Legend.BorderColor = 'Black'
    $Chart.Legends.Add($Legend)
    $chart.Series[$series.name].LegendText = "#VALX (#VALY%)"
    $chart.Series[$series.name].Legend = $Legend.name



}


$mailHash = @{"Email Set"=$emailPer;"No Email"=$noEmailPer}
#modify this path
$outFilePic= "d:\temp\stala.jpeg"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization
$Chart = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
$Chart.Width = 1400
$Chart.Height = 800
$Chart.Left = 10
$Chart.Top = 10
$Chart.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
$Chart.BorderColor = 'Black'
$Chart.BorderDashStyle = 'Solid'    
$ChartTypes = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType]
$data = @{"10"="5";"20"="5";"30"="100";}
$data2 = @{"100"="1";"200"="49";"300"="50";}
drawPie $chart $data $ChartTypes::Pie
drawPie $chart $data2 $ChartTypes::Bar
$Chart.SaveImage($outFilePic, 'jpeg')
```

Comment: Tks so much mate! I really appreciate it. You'r saver :D

Comment: hmmm, I got a problem when I try to combine pie chart and bar graph in one. I got an error "_The chart area 
contains incompatible chart types. For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same chart area_" . Is there any possibility to solve?

Comment: @Ender I have updated the code with Pie and Bar chart in one.Can you check?

Comment: It works like a charm. Tks so much. I'm trying to separate their sections. Because when I put the title for it, it isn't able to go onto their fields as well as the description box is also being merged.